# How can I get path of resource under WEB-INF/class folder (java ee web dynamic project)

Tags: java, servlets

I develop web dynamic project in Eclipse. One file, file named 'users.txt' is located under classes folder (WEB-INF/classes/users.txt).

How I can get relative path of this file in class (base class, not servlet class)? I will use that path for append several lines of text.

Christian this is the code that works for reading. Problem is I don't know how to create object for writing (output) in the same file with relative path.

```
public Products(){
    try{
        InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("products.txt");    
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        readProducts(br);
        in.close();
            br.close();


    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("File doesn't exists");
    }
    }

    public void readProducts(BufferedReader in) throws NumberFormatException, IOException{

        String id="";
        String name="";
        double price=0;

        StringTokenizer st;
        String line;

        while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
            st=new StringTokenizer(line,";");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                id=st.nextToken();
                name=st.nextToken();
                price=Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());           
            }           
            products.put(id,new Product(id,name,price));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some codes at least what have you tried so far?

Comment: You're looking for the solution in the wrong direction. You are not supposed to write to the deploy folder during runtime, let alone the deploy classpath. Put the file in a fixed location outside the deploy folder. Additional bonus is that your current problem is instantly solved this way. By the way, the normal practice is to use a SQL database for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking you should not rely on modifying files in your web application directory.

One of the reasons is that servlet container is not obligated to extract your `.war` file to the fs, it could, in theory, run your web application from memory. Yeah, Tomcat and most of the containers do unpack `.war` but there is nothing in Java EE specs that says that they must do this.

Anyway, if you think that this worth the risk you can use [ServletContext.getRealPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) to get location of the file inside your webapp directory.

This should look something like this:

1. Create a file `myfile` under your webapp root (should be located **in the same folder** as `WEB-INF` in your `.war`).
2. do something like this in your servlet (or anywhere where you can access servlet context):

   String filePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("myfile");

Note that in order for this to work you should be able to fetch the file with request, like: `http://<host>:<port>/<contextPath>/myfile` (see method docs for details)