# Open a Pdf File generated in java web Application

Tags: jakarta-ee, pdf

I am generating a report in my web application successfully. I need this file to be available at client side and I have done this:

```
 String serverHomeDir = System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME");
        String reportDestination = serverHomeDir + "/Reports/" + user + "_" + church + "_" + currdate + ".pdf";
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportDestination);
```

The Pdf File Available on the Directory can be Opened Successfully. However the One downloading on Client Side cannot be Opened. It is giving this Error:

[image]

What am I doing Wrong or not doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach your file as a byte array to your response:

```
 String serverHomeDir = System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME");
 String reportDestination = serverHomeDir + "/Reports/" + user + "_" + church + "_" + currdate + ".pdf";

 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(reportDestination));

 // Fast way to copy a bytearray from InputStream to OutputStream
 org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(fis, response.getOutputStream());
 response.setContentType("application/pdf");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportDestination);
 response.flushBuffer();
```

Comment: `IOUtils.copy(fis, response.getOutputStream());` Fails on Method Copy. Which Class is this?