# Error in forwarding to file report

Tags: java, spring-boot, jasper-reports, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to print my data from database using SpringBoot, Hibernate, and Jasper Reports. Below is my code for generating the report:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "report/manpowerMainReport2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String generateReport(
            @RequestParam("formId") Long formId, 
            Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws JRException, 
            IOException,
            NamingException {

            /*String rptFmt="pdf";
            Log.info("Report Format =" +rptFmt);*/  
    String reportFileName = "/src/main/resources/static/jasper/Blank_A4_Landscape.jasper";
    JasperReportDao jrdao = new JasperReportDao();

    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = jrdao.getConnection();

        JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(reportFileName, null, new JREmptyDataSource());


        HashMap<String, Object> hmParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hmParams.put("formId", formId);

        JasperReport jasperReport = jrdao.getCompiledFile(reportFileName,request);

        jrdao.generateReportPDF(response, hmParams, jasperReport, conn);

    } 

    catch (SQLException sqlExp) {
        System.out.println("Exception::" + sqlExp.toString());
    } 

    finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
                conn = null;
                } 
            catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, when I run the code on localhost, I get the following error:

> Database Connected 2017-04-27 09:47:55.366 ERROR 2624 ---
>   [io-8080-exec-27] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     :
>   Forwarding to error page from request [/report/manpowerMainReport2]
>   due to exception [java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   \src\main\resources\static\jasper\Blank_A4_Landscape.jasper]
>
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   \src\main\resources\static\jasper\Blank_A4_Landscape.jasper   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:127)
>   ~[jasperreports-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]  at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:116)
>   ~[jasperreports-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]  at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillToFile(JasperFillManager.java:497)
>   ~[jasperreports-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]  at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(JasperFillManager.java:888)
>   ~[jasperreports-6.2.2.jar:6.2.2]  at
>   com.mida.controller.LoadJasperReport.generateReport(LoadJasperReport.java:82)
>   ~[LoadJasperReport.class:na]

Does anyone have a solution for this error? If you guys have any working example for creating report using Jasper integrated with spring boot and hibernate please do share the link here for my reference.

Comment: The error is telling you: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \src\main\resources\static\jasper\Blank_A4_Landscape.jasper The file is not on your classpath, probably not being included in your build?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting 'File Not Found Exception' with JasperReports on Java Web Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181296/getting-file-not-found-exception-with-jasperreports-on-java-web-application)