# best way to load external files in j2EE?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, glassfish-4

I am trying to deploy a REST web service. I use glassfish as a web server. 
I have a problem when i try to open an external file. in other words I want to read a file that is in the web-inf folder named "config.xml".

When I used a Java application (not web application), I used the following code to open the file but now it does not work

```
String path = new File (".") GetCanonicalPath () + "/ config.xml".
```

Cordially

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get path of resource under WEB-INF/class folder (java ee web dynamic project)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156991/how-can-i-get-path-of-resource-under-web-inf-class-folder-java-ee-web-dynamic-p) - or just search for `ServletContext.getRealPath` here on SO, you'll find many references.

Comment: use @Context private ServeltContext myContext;

Answer (score 2):

I guess this line can be useful to you:

```
File image = new File(req.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "/carrousel/"+ req.getParameter("fileName"));
```

I use it to create a new File in the server.